# Shiny Conditional Statements

Tags: r, shiny

I am having problems using conditional statements in Shiny.  I wan the user to be able to select data for the Y values and it will change the type of chart displayed.  When the type of data is numeric the chart displays fine. But when the type of data is text I want the chart to change to a histogram and just count the number of instances. The two scenarios I am working with are contract spending in the selected category vs the number of contracts in the selected category.  my server code is below.  I just need to be able to switch the type of graph from bar to histogram based on the value selected.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
spend <- read.csv("C:/Users/William/Documents/First_Rstudio/App-1/data/CENTCOMdata.csv")
output$GovSpend <- renderPlot({
    spend <- spend[spend$Contracting.Agency.Name == input$agency,]

if(typeof(input$yval) = "double"){ggplot(spend, aes_string(x = input$xlab, y = ylab fill = "Tier.1.Contract.Category")) + 
        geom_bar(na.rm = TRUE, stat= "identity")
    }    
else {ggplot(spend, aes_string(x = input$xlab, fill= "Tier.1.Contract.Category")) + 
        geom_bar()}
})
})
```

Each graph works fine on it's own.  I just can't get the if statement to work. When it renders to the web, it always defaults to the histogram regardless of the data type selected for the yval or which comes first in the if statement.

the UI is here:

```
library(shiny)
spend <- read.csv("C:/Users/William/Documents/First_Rstudio/App-1/data/CENTCOMdata.csv")
shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("All Gov't Spend"),

    sidebarLayout(

     sidebarPanel( 
        selectInput("xlab", label = "Select X Values",
                choices = colnames(spend),
        selected = "FY"
                ),

        selectInput("yval", label = "Select y Values",
                    choices = colnames(spend),
                selected = "Action_Absolute_Value"
        ),

    selectInput("agency", label = "Select Agency",
                choices = levels(spend$Contracting.Agency.Name)
                ),
        selectInput("Country", label = "Select Country",
                choices = levels(spend$Principal.Place.of.Performance.Country.Name))

),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("GovSpend")
)
)
))
```

Comment: I updated with the UI.  The elements that the yval is coming from are any of the columns in the data set, so people can build the chart elements.  The Action.Obligation values read as type double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User input values from HTML elements are always strings. So whether `input$yval=="Action.Obligation"` or `input$yval=="Tier.1.Contract.Category"` the `input$yval` is always a character, never double. You don't want to check the typeof `input$yval`, you want to check the data type of `spend[[input$yval]]` because that will actually look at the column in your data.frame. I suggest you change your if statement to

```
if ( is.numeric(spend[[input$yval]]) ) {
    ggplot(spend, aes_string(x = input$xlab, y = ylab fill ="Tier.1.Contract.Category")) + 
        geom_bar(na.rm = TRUE, stat= "identity")
} else {
    ggplot(spend, aes_string(x = input$xlab, fill= "Tier.1.Contract.Category")) + 
        geom_bar()
}
```

Comment: Works.  Thanks!  One thing I don't understand though.  Why the double brackets around input$yval? I thought this was how to subset a list.  I did not know one had been created.

Comment: A data.frame is basically a list. You could also do `spend[, input$yval]`